# push to first free place in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What would be the most beautiful way of doing so?

`var arr = [1,2,3,undefined, null,,null];`

pushing `4` will output:

`[1,2,3,4,null,,null]`

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: why? use your browser's console for testing.

Comment: For better your code understanding

Comment: it's clear..push an item to the first free place in the array. no ordering, no duplicated, i never said any of those things.

Comment: `null` is not a free item,

Comment: Looks like you are trying to replace first null with 4?

Comment: @thefourtheye - yes i agree, my question is not defined right. I meant the null is considered free also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ind = arr.join().split(',').indexOf('');
if (ind !== -1)
    arr[ind] = 4
```

Comment: well, it's nice, but fails with this `[1,2,3,,,null]`

Comment: nice, you've used a method I have found years ago and published on stackoverflow ;) This is correctly the most beautiful way.

Comment: @vsync: Wait.. so you already knew the answer? And why is this the best way? It's not very efficient, which to me is ugly

Comment: sweet, did you forgot about it, or...? what was the point of the question then?

Comment: And I concur, this is ugly, there has to be a more robust way.

Comment: it's the best because for it NOT to be efficient, it would need to run on a huge array. for 99% of the cases this is perfect.

Comment: @vsync: Again... did you already know the answer? Why did you post the question?

Comment: @musefan - yes I knew how to do it. I wanted to put it in stackoverflow by a way of code competition, to get the best result, to future developers could come and get exactly the best solution to this problem.

Comment: @vsync: This isn't how SO works. Firstly, you should have included your attempt at the problem. Secondly, you should not ask questions that are "Primarily opinion based"... and it's even worse if your standards of judgement conclude this answer to be the "best"

Comment: I've created a page with a valuable question and there are very good answers here, that future devs who would come here could learn from. no harm caused, chill. and obviously this is the best answer, if you think it is not, please prove so with jsPref.

Comment: @vsync: Fair enough... this method is pretty quick... but why

Answer (score 0):

You can do that;

```
function push(arr, to_be_added) {
    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i] == null || arr[i].length == 0 || arr[i] == undefined) {
            arr[i] = to_be_added;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv7s5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may try to this :

```
var arr = [1,2,3,,,null];
var indx = arr.indexOf(null)||arr.indexOf("");
if (indx !== -1)
arr[indx] = 4
alert(arr.sort());
```

This will return that you need .. for both type of Array .